# Deserialize Root class

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a root class

```
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a class Data as show here

```
    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("timings")]
        public Timings Timings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public Date Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("meta")]
        public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    }
```

And Timings is a class also

I properly deserialize the root class like this

```
 salatjson = e.Result;
 Root model =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(salatjson);
```

How can I get Timings class from model?

Comment: `var timings = model.Data.Timings`? Are you using Visual Studio? Have you tried to enter a *dot* after you've written `model` (one line after `Root model = ...`)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `data` property is set and that the ojson contains the `timings` in the data object:

```
 salatjson = e.Result;
 Root model =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(salatjson);
 // with null safety
 var timings = model?.Data?.Timings;
```

Getting it as a list, is another thing altogether. Your json should be like this:

```
"data": {
   "timings": [
       {// timing object},
       {// timing object},
    ]
}
```

And your class like this:

```
    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("timings")]
        public List<Timings> Timings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public Date Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("meta")]
        public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I can it in that way but I struggle to get it as a list a tried many conversion but doesn't work. Any idea ? Thanks so much

Comment: Check the updated answer for deserializing to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You should really go all the way around. If you already have the json file, you can use visual studio to do the heavy work for you.

So, copy your json file and on Visual Studio use

```
Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes
```

Now you won't have to worry about deserialization.

**Update**

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(salatjson);

public class Timings    {
    public string Fajr { get; set; } 
    public string Sunrise { get; set; } 
    public string Dhuhr { get; set; } 
    public string Asr { get; set; } 
    public string Sunset { get; set; } 
    public string Maghrib { get; set; } 
    public string Isha { get; set; } 
    public string Imsak { get; set; } 
    public string Midnight { get; set; } 
}

public class Weekday    {
    public string en { get; set; } 
    public string ar { get; set; } 
}

public class Month    {
    public int number { get; set; } 
    public string en { get; set; } 
    public string ar { get; set; } 
}

public class Designation    {
    public string abbreviated { get; set; } 
    public string expanded { get; set; } 
}

public class Hijri    {
    public string date { get; set; } 
    public string format { get; set; } 
    public string day { get; set; } 
    public Weekday weekday { get; set; } 
    public Month month { get; set; } 
    public string year { get; set; } 
    public Designation designation { get; set; } 
    public List<object> holidays { get; set; } 
}

public class Weekday2    {
    public string en { get; set; } 
}

public class Month2    {
    public int number { get; set; } 
    public string en { get; set; } 
}

public class Designation2    {
    public string abbreviated { get; set; } 
    public string expanded { get; set; } 
}

public class Gregorian    {
    public string date { get; set; } 
    public string format { get; set; } 
    public string day { get; set; } 
    public Weekday2 weekday { get; set; } 
    public Month2 month { get; set; } 
    public string year { get; set; } 
    public Designation2 designation { get; set; } 
}

public class Date    {
    public string readable { get; set; } 
    public string timestamp { get; set; } 
    public Hijri hijri { get; set; } 
    public Gregorian gregorian { get; set; } 
}

public class Params    {
    public int Fajr { get; set; } 
    public int Isha { get; set; } 
}

public class Method    {
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public Params @params { get; set; } 
}

public class Offset    {
    public int Imsak { get; set; } 
    public int Fajr { get; set; } 
    public int Sunrise { get; set; } 
    public int Dhuhr { get; set; } 
    public int Asr { get; set; } 
    public int Maghrib { get; set; } 
    public int Sunset { get; set; } 
    public int Isha { get; set; } 
    public int Midnight { get; set; } 
}

public class Meta    {
    public double latitude { get; set; } 
    public double longitude { get; set; } 
    public string timezone { get; set; } 
    public Method method { get; set; } 
    public string latitudeAdjustmentMethod { get; set; } 
    public string midnightMode { get; set; } 
    public string school { get; set; } 
    public Offset offset { get; set; } 
}

public class Data    {
    public Timings timings { get; set; } 
    public Date date { get; set; } 
    public Meta meta { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public int code { get; set; } 
    public string status { get; set; } 
    public Data data { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: the JSON is getting from a server. The link of the server is : http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timings/:date_or_timestamp?latitude=51.508515&longitude=-0.1254872

Comment: Thanks . I come to deserialize the root class. My question is how can I get List<Timing> from root ?